# Einstein ChatBot - Dynamic Choice output: how to use in further action?

Tags: einstein, bots

As a new learner I followed the Einstein Bot Cookbook guide on dynamic menus. The problem is that I struggle with using the value chosen by the user (which is stored in 'Appointments' object) for next apex action. I'm aware that there should be an @invocableVariable which allows object as an input but don't know how to write it.

the apex class for dynamic menu is

```
public with sharing class CookbookBot_GetOpenAppointments {

  @InvocableMethod(label='Get Open Appointments')
  public static List<List<Bot_Appointment__c>> getOpenAppointments(List<String> sEmails) {

    String sEmail = sEmails[0];


    List<Bot_Appointment__c> appointments = [SELECT Id, Name, JobType__c, 
                                                    AppointmentDate__c, AppointmentSlot__c 
                                             FROM Bot_Appointment__c 
                                             WHERE Contact__r.Email =:sEmail 
                                             AND Status__c IN ('New','Scheduled')];


    List<List<Bot_Appointment__c>> appointmentList = new List<List<Bot_Appointment__c>>();


    appointmentList.add(appointments);

    return appointmentList;
  }
}
```

So I'd like to use an option chosen by the user and stored in 'Appointments' object to use in another apex class and let's say change the appointment status. I could I achieve this?

Comment: welcome to SFSE Piotr!.  the class as coded won't compile as the method definition isn't right; use [edit] to fix. InvocableVariables are covered in the Apex Developer Guide

Comment: hi copredy, thanks for the worm welcome, I fixed the class - it returns several appointments nicely. Now in the bot editor I stored these appointments in 'openAppointments' object. The thing is that I can't figure out how to write next apex class for the apex call in the bot editor to use open appointment chosen by the chat user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the apex class given in The Einstein Bot Cookbook as an example doesn't fit a scenario when you need to reuse the option chosen by a chat user. We need to generate list of strings as an output not list of object. Then we can easily store the output from the dynamic menu as a Variable(text) and use it in next apex class.

Comment: Could you perhaps share your solution?